# Как вытащить все данные конкретного пользователя из БД sqlite3 в дискорд боте?

Tags: python, discord, sqlite3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вытащить все данные пользователя из БД sqlite3 в дискорд боте используя ('команда'@никнейм)?

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо было просто в качестве второго аргумента, написать любые входные данные)
А так всё работает прекрасно